# Objective-C 'RootViewController' may not respond to '-parseXMLFileAtURL:' error in xCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xml-parsing

I have this error when building and running my project in xCode:
`RootViewController` may not respond to `-parseXMLFileAtURL:`
I'm attempting to develop the basic Apple RSS Reader from the tutorial at:

http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

my section of code that this error is occurring in looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
    if ([stories count] == 0)
    {
         NSString * path = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog"; 
         [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path]; 
    }
    cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60); 
}
```

can anybody explain why this `parseXMLFileAtURL` command gives so much heartache?

Thanks

UPDATED*****

I also define `parseXMLFileAtURL` in the same file; however, I placed that section of the code after the `viewDidAppear` method (my bad).  So when I change the order of the methods that error goes away.  But when I do that, I get another error, maybe you guys can help with that error too! here it is:

Class `RootViewController` does not implement the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol

within this section of code:

```
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL]; 
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL]; 
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; 
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; 
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; 
    [rssParser parse];
}
```

The error occurs after the line: `[rssParser setDelegate:self];` - what might be wrong with that?

Comment: Could you post the error please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your second question that `RootViewController` does not conform to the  `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol. Just add it like this in your `RootViewController.h` file:

```
@interface  RootViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> { .....
```

Comment: in my header file I already have: @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {//method details//}@end.  why would that not already do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes, just add the <NSXMLParserDelegate> before the {

Answer (score 1):

Silly question: Does your `RootViewcontroller` class have a method named `-parseXMLFileAtURL:` defined? If `-parseXMLFileAtURL:` comes after the method that calls it, you'll also need to declare it in your header.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `parseXMLFileAtURL` defined in your `RootViewController.m`

```
-(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)url
{   
    ... 
}
```

And make sure you have it defined in your header as:

```
-(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)url;
```

Also, make sure that when you try to get the contents from the web, you're using an `NSURL`, not an `NSString`. You can instantiate a NSURL with a string by:

```
NSURL *urlFromString = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://..."];
```

Comment: Nice, thanks dude, check out my OP for an updated question though.

Comment: Alright, as far as your NSURL comment goes; I tried changing my NSString string in my viewDidAppear method to what you suggested and now i get an error from the [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path] line directly underneath it.  The error says "Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSURL *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument..."